# Angular Materials 2 - Sidenav - How to open/close sidenav from Service

Tags: angular, angular-material2

My sidebar () is in a component called 'program-body.component'.

program-body.component.html:

```
<mat-sidenav-container id="body_container" class="row zeroMargin fullheight">
    <!-- This is the HTML for the inside of the modal -->
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav id="sidebarContainer" mode="side" class="fullheight">
        <!-- Sidebar HTML body -->
    </mat-sidenav>
    <button md-mini-fab class="example-fab" (click)="sidenav.toggle(); dataService.sidebarClicked();">
        <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I have a button in a completely different component ('othercomponent.component') where I want to be able to call functions, such as (click)="sidenav.toggle()" found within my sidebar component.

other-component.component.html:

```
<button mat-raised-button style="width:49%" (click)="parseUserInput()">Read Transit Stops</button>
```

other-component.component.ts:

```
public parseUserInput(){
    //I want to run the sidenav.toggle function now
    //   something like 'this.globalService.closeSidebar();'
    dialogModal.open();
}
```

How do I make these sidenav functions available globally?  Ideally, I want a way to make functions within the 'program-body.component' accessible within a 'globalservice' service that when called from another component that inherits it, it can control it.

Comment: We need to see some code in order to be able to help.

Comment: Please go through [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Lynx Added code to better explain it.  Sorry for the lack of code.

Comment: @DavidR I've added code to better explain the issue.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You were right with thinking about using a "globalservice" service :)

You could try to make an injectable service like this:

```
import { Observable ,  Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ShareService {

    // Observable source
    private emitToggled = new Subject();

    // Observable stream
    toggleEmitted$ = this.emitToggled.asObservable();

    // Service toggle command
    emitToggle() {
        this.emitDeleted.next();
    }
}
```

Put it in your `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({ providers: [ ShareService ] });
```

And then inject it in your `program-body.component`:

```
constructor(private share : ShareService) {  }
```

Subscribe to it with:

```
this.share.toggleEmitted$.subscribe(() => {
    console.log("toggled!");
});
```

Inject in in your `othercomponent.component` same as above.

Emit your toggle with: `this.share.emitToggle();`

This is explained in the Angular documentation found here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use a emiter, just a variable

//In your service

```
@Injectable()
export class ShareService {
  toggle:boolean;
}
```

//In your program-body.component

```
<div *ngIf="toggle">toggle is true</div>

get toggle()
{
    return this.shareService.toggle;
}
```

//In your othercomponent.component

```
set toggle(value)
{
   this.shareService.toggle=value;
}
get toggle()
{
    return this.shareService.toggle;
}
click()
{
    toggle=!toggle;
}
```

Comment: I've added code to the example.  The function I want to call is built within the 'sidebar' component library (Angular Materials 2).  I've initialised the component within an Angular component, and I need to call functions that modify that component, within another Angular component, when they are currently only available within the Angular component they were initialised in.